# Pre-processing (standardization and exponential smoothing) in expanding window cross-validation for time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, standardization, exponential-smoothing

I am currently working on a time series forecasting task using an expanding window cross-validation approach. My dataset is created using the sliding window technique (Window: 4, Horizon: 1). During the cross-validation process, I need to perform pre-processing steps such as standardization and exponential smoothing on my data before training and evaluating the models.

I have commented out the pre-processing steps (train_x_scaled, val_x_scaled, scaler = standardize_data_sliding_window(train_x_cv, val_x_cv)) as I am unsure about the correct implementation within the cross-validation loop.

How can I appropriately pre-process the training and validation data using standardization and exponential smoothing techniques within the expanding window cross-validation framework? Specifically, how can I ensure that the pre-processing is done correctly (avoid leakage) for each fold of the cross-validation?

Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

````
# Time-series expanding window validation
# with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

tf.random.set_seed(42)
eval_scores = []
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
def cross_validation(combination, train_x=train_x, train_y=train_y, tscv=tscv):
    smape_scores = []
    mdape_scores = []

    # Cross-Validation
    for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(train_x):
        train_x_cv, val_x_cv = train_x[train_index], train_x[test_index]
        train_y_cv, val_y_cv = train_y[train_index], train_y[test_index]

        # Pre-Processing
        # train_x_scaled, val_x_scaled, scaler = standardize_data_sliding_window(train_x_cv, val_x_cv)
        # ...

        # Model Architecture and Training
        for i in range(combination.hidden_layers):
            model_cv.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(combination.hidden_neurons,
                                                activation="relu",
                                                kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.HeNormal(),
                                                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(combination.regularization)))
        model_cv.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear",
                                            kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.HeNormal(),
                                            kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(combination.regularization)))

        model_cv.compile(loss=smape_loss,
                        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=combination.learning_rate),
                        metrics=[metric_mdape, "mae", "mse"])  # Backpropagation

        model_cv.fit(train_x_cv, train_y_cv, epochs=50, batch_size=combination.batch_size, verbose=0)

        predictions = model_cv.predict(val_x_cv)
        smape_score, mdape_score = evaluate_pred(val_y_cv, predictions)

        smape_scores.append(smape_score)
        mdape_scores.append(mdape_score)

    mean_smape = np.mean(smape_scores)
    mean_mdape = np.mean(mdape_scores)
    hyperparameters = {
        'learning_rate': combination.learning_rate,
        'batch_size': combination.batch_size,
        'regularization': combination.regularization,
        'hidden_neurons': combination.hidden_neurons,
        'hidden_layers': combination.hidden_layers
    }
    print(f"Current mean SMAPE: {mean_smape}, Current hyperparameters: {hyperparameters}")
    return mean_smape, mean_mdape, hyperparameters

random_combinations = random.sample(combinations, 5)
results = map(cross_validation, random_combinations)

optimal_smape = float('inf')
optimal_mdape = float('inf')
optimal_hyperparameters = {}
for result in results:
    smape, mdape, hyperparameters = result
    if smape < optimal_smape:
        optimal_smape = smape
        optimal_mdape = mdape
        optimal_hyperparameters = hyperparameters
print("Best Hyperparameters:", optimal_hyperparameters)
print("Best SMAPE Score:", optimal_smape)
print("Best MDAPE Score:", optimal_mdape)
```
````